# Generate two elements conditionally during list comprehension

Tags: python-3.x, iterator, list-comprehension, python-datetime

The task is to parse human-readable timeframes to python friendly. The timeframes can include the following formats only:

- '9:00 AM–9:45 PM'
- '9:00 AM–Midnight'
- '9:00 AM–Noon'
- 'Noon–9:45 PM'
- 'Noon–Midnight'
- '24 Hours'

The following piece of code works for all the cases except for '24 Hours'.

```
data = ['9:00 AM–9:45 PM',
 '9:00 AM–Midnight',
 '9:00 AM–Noon',
 '9:00 PM–10:00 PM',
 'Noon–9:45 PM',
 'Noon–Midnight',
 '24 Hours']

for slot in data:
    print([[time(0, 0), time(23, 59)] if item == "24 Hours"    # Need help here
           else time(12, 0)if item == "Noon"
           else time(0, 0)if item == "Midnight"
           else datetime.strptime(item, "%I:%M %p").time()
           for item in slot.split("–")] )
```

Output:

```
[datetime.time(9, 0), datetime.time(21, 45)]
[datetime.time(9, 0), datetime.time(0, 0)]
[datetime.time(9, 0), datetime.time(12, 0)]
[datetime.time(21, 0), datetime.time(22, 0)]
[datetime.time(12, 0), datetime.time(21, 45)]
[datetime.time(12, 0), datetime.time(0, 0)]
[[datetime.time(0, 0), datetime.time(23, 59)]]   # Need help here
```

Although I partially can, the out is a list-of-list for `24 hours`. I'm looking for just a list.
Can somebody help me out with this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a regex:

```
import re
print(re.match('^[0-9][0-9] hours', '02 hours') is not None) # True
print(re.match('^[0-9][0-9] hours', '9:00 AM–9:45 PM') is not None) # False
```

You will maybe have to do minor modifications the regex depending on the exact format of the "24 hours" datetime